# Rest API - Getting one-off information for an object

Tags: rest, restful-architecture, restful-url, api-design

Here is my example. I have a basic rest api for a Member. Simple CRUD. Project manager says "we need an endpoint that will return the remaining pension amount for that member.

I get this stuff a lot where they want a very specific piece of information about an object.I don't want to include this in the Read request as the calculation can be time consuming. So, how do I do this in a RESTful way??

Comment: The computation effort required to calculate a property has nothing to do with REST. This is a question about services, backend architecture, services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new endpoint called `Pension`, which could have a `RemainingAmount` property (and probably a `RemainingCurrencyIso` one, too), and expose that through a [link](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html#level3) from the `Member` resource like so:

`GET /api/member/{id}/pension`

Answer (score 0):

If this is a field of the user object, you could have a separate url param

`?fields=RemainingAmount`

In the absence of the fields param, you just return the full object.